# OpenGL Multitexture - Second texture operation has no effect

Tags: ios, opengl, textures

I'm doing a multi texture operation that blends a certain amount of grey into a texture, then further tints the texture with another color. Note that the original texture has pre-multiplied alpha.

Here's the code:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [texture_ name]);
GLfloat g[4] = { grey, grey, grey, grey };
glTexEnvfv(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_COLOR, g);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB,      GL_INTERPOLATE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_RGB,         GL_TEXTURE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_RGB,     GL_SRC_COLOR);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC1_RGB,         GL_TEXTURE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND1_RGB,     GL_SRC_ALPHA);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC2_RGB,         GL_CONSTANT);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND2_RGB,     GL_SRC_COLOR);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_ALPHA,    GL_REPLACE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_ALPHA,       GL_TEXTURE);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gTexID1);
GLfloat col[4] = { (float)color_.r/255.0, (float)color_.g/255.0, (float)color_.b/255.0, 1.0 };
glTexEnvfv(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_COLOR, col);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB,      GL_MODULATE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_RGB,         GL_PREVIOUS);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_RGB,     GL_SRC_COLOR);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC1_RGB,         GL_CONSTANT);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND1_RGB,     GL_SRC_COLOR);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_ALPHA,    GL_REPLACE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_ALPHA,       GL_PREVIOUS);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_ALPHA,   GL_SRC_ALPHA);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

The first part works just fine, but the second part has no effect whatsoever.
The texture name gTexID1 is really dummy since I use the constant color to tint the texture, I simply create it with a call to: glGenTextures(1, &gTexID1).
I have checked the value of the color of course, it's not white.

I have shamelessly copied most of the code from [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Combiners).

Any idea as to why this fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though it is a dummy texture, I believe it is not enough to call glGenTextures. You must also call glTexImage2D to give it a size. Also check if you get any error code from glGetError.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I marked datenwolf's answer as the right one as he answered first.

Comment: @Guy: Actually I answered first, but no problem ;-)  And glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

The naming of some OpenGL functions is a bit confusing. `glGenTextures` does not generate texture objects, but unused texture names. In older OpenGL versions (<=OpenGL-2.1) you were even allowed to do name management yourself and not use `glGenTextures` at all. Just using `glBindTexture` with a unused name was sufficient. The actual texture object is created with a call to `glTexImage2D`.

May I ask why you're going through the struggles of texture combiners and are not simply using a fragment shader for this?

Comment: Awww, that was it, I had to call glTexImage2D to actually create this dummy texture. Fairly unintuitive considering I don't even use it in the combiner.
I'm not using shaders because I'm using OpenGL 1.1 and switching to v2 would mean switching the framework (Cocos2D) that does the bulk of the openGL work to v2, which means lots of hassle :-) Not sure it's worth it if I don't have any other fancy stuff to do in OpenGL.
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Guy: You can use shaders without doing a full switch to >OpenGL-2, they're available as a extension and thus can be used perfectly well in a OpenGL-1.1 infrastructure. Just remember to clean up, after you used them.